# Line break not working as intended in php

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to create a square, created of smaller red and blue squares. The problem is, when i want to use 
 something wierd happens, every new line is off by 20 px.

```
<style>
    .box{
        background-color: red;
        position: relative;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        margin-left: 3px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        float:left;
    }
    .box1{
        background-color: blue;
        position: relative;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        margin-left: 3px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        float:left;
    }
</style>

<?php
for($a=0;$a<4;$a++){
  for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
    {
        echo "<div class= box> </div>";
        echo "<div class= box1> </div>";
    }
    echo "<br />";
    for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
    {
        echo "<div class= box> </div>";
        echo "<div class= box1> </div>";
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCPNH.png)

Answer (score 1):

Using relative position is the problem. Use `display:inline-block` instead.
Also you can accomplish this only using 2 for loops.

```
<style>
    .box{
        background-color: red;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        margin-left: 3px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        display: inline-block;
        
    }
    .box1{
        background-color: blue;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        margin-left: 3px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

<?php
for($a=0;$a<8;$a++){
  for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
    {
        echo "<div class= box> </div>";
        echo "<div class= box1> </div>";
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to break `float` is to use `clear` style attribute. For example add this to your styles:

```
br{
   clear:both;
}
```

`<br />` will now reset the float of the divs after it, so the next ones will be in new line.

[Example in here](https://jsfiddle.net/avkpfbtg/).

---

**Please note that `class` attribute should be in quotes, your code is not a valid `HTML`. To make it valid use one of these:**

```
echo "<div class='box'> </div>";
```

or

```
echo '<div class="box"> </div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view you have to add one main div as like below code and have to add float left and width to 100%;

```html
<style>
    .box{
        background-color: red;
        position: relative;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        margin-left: 3px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        float:left;
    }
    .box1{
        background-color: blue;
        position: relative;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        margin-left: 3px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        float:left;
    }
    .main {
        float:left;
        width:100%;
    }
</style>

<?php
for($a=0;$a<4;$a++){
    echo "<div class='main'>";
  for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
    {
        echo "<div class= box> </div>";
        echo "<div class= box1> </div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<div class='main'>";
    for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
    {
        echo "<div class= box> </div>";
        echo "<div class= box1> </div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```